# what type of statistical analysis is needed

Tags: multiple-regression

I wish to examine the relationship between individuals with (cardiovascular disesase) and 9 predictors of coping strategies on the Dependant variable of Depression. If I want to assess whether the coping strategies predict depression in men and women differently, do I add gender to the 9 predictors (making 10 predictors) and do I needed to dummy code the gender variable or because it's dictomous alerady can I ignore this step.  Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: How is depression measured? One some scale? As a 0/1?

Comment: Thank you I will use the Dass to measure depresssion in men and women who have CVD. So I gather this would be 1 way anova??

Comment: @Catherine I think he means is it a binary variable or can it take on a number of values over some range.

Comment: @catherine CVD=cardiovscular disease? DASS=Depression Anxiety Stress Scales? Isn't that three different scores? How are each recorded? the question should be clarified

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you want to test if gender is a predictor, add it to the predictors. It depends if what model you're using can handle factor variables. If it can't and can only handle numeric, you will need to dummy code it.

Comment: Wasn't sure here the CERQ emotion regulation strategies questionnaire has 9 variables and I was going to test these to determine if some of these emotion strategies (IVs) was more predictive of Depression (DV) but I also wanted to see if Gender influenced the relationship between the emotional strategies that are used. Now sure if I should be putting 9 or 10 ivs in  power analysis and which statistical tests to run, I'm thing one way anova, multiple regression and moderated multiple regression. However also intereseted in whether Cognitive reappraisal moderates depression in the entire group.

Comment: Not sure what CERQ is but sure, you are essentially testing if gender is a predictor which is fine, it doesn't have to be of the same type (emotion strategy) of your other IVs for it to be tested. Those tests are fine but remember your predictive output is essentially categorical (I assume) so your regressions will have to match this.